# Go to next item in list on error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am pulling websites from a list and want to test, whether they are up or down. The code below works fine as long as they are up, but as soon as something is wrong with one of these urls, I get an error message and the whole scrip stops.

What I want to achieve: Error message == website not working therefore print down and move to next item in list.

```
import urllib2
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError, URLError

def checkurl(z):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/20.0.1 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    headers = { 'User-Agent':user_agent }
    link = "http://"+z
    req = Request(link, headers = headers)
    try:
        page_open = urlopen(req)
    except HTTPError, e:
        print "down"
    else:
        print 'up'
    #print urllib2.urlopen('http://'+z).read()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Videos/python/onion/qweqweqweq.py", line 48, in <module>
    checkurl(x)
  File "/home/user/Videos/python/onion/qweqweqweq.py", line 23, in checkurl
    page_open = urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 401, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 419, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1211, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1178, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 962, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 996, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 818, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 780, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 761, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/home/user/Videos/python/onion/qweqweqweq.py", line 5, in create_connection
    sock.connect(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 369, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 236, in __negotiatesocks5
    raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: posting the error traceback would be helpful...

Comment: are you sure the URL is correct (i.e. the contents of `z`)? one of the `z` values you are using appears invalid (causing the networking module to bug out).

Comment: hi @isedev . I am a bit of a noob, but would it be possible to assume that the website is down regardless of the error and move to the next item in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to "would it be possible to assume that the website is down regardless of the error", then this will do it:

```
req = Request(link, headers = headers)
try:
    page_open = urlopen(req)
except:
    print "down"
else:
    print 'up'
```

Comment: just tried this and it seems to work! many thanks! ps. I seriously hope to achieve a similar level as you pros someday in the future...

Comment: why the downvote? it may not be elegant, but it is the only answer to the actual question in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You are catching `HTTPError`, but what is thrown is `Socks5Error`.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `Socks5Error` in your `except` clause. Look at the traceback:

```
raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
```

Note that this wouldn't have happened if you used [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib2`. The interface is a lot clearer, the documentation better.